# ExtJS 4.2.2 настройка скрола для Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

Доброе время суток.

Набросал пример [кода](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q84), пытаюсь решить задачу что бы при раскрытии группы если коле вылазит за рамки появлялся горизонтальный скрол для прокрутки всей таблици.

Пробывал разные комбинации, из которых оставил в комментариях к коду.

Спасибо за попытку помощи )

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        cls: 'body',
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        layout:{
             tableAttrs: {
                  style: {width:'100%'}
             },
             type:'table'
         },
        autoScroll: true,
```

Этот огрызок кода помог частично исправить ситуацию.